# ie7 bottom scrollbar hell

Tags: css, internet-explorer

http://redlineautoleasing.com/beta/

what could be causing the bottom scrollbar? i cant figure it out.

i tried this
http://blog.josh420.com/archives/2007/11/fixing-the-ie-overflow-vertical-scrollbar-bug.aspx
but the page kind of got messed up the bottom content got chopped off.

Comment: I'm getting javascript errors on IE7 that prevents running the pngfix script.

Answer (score 7):

From your CSS:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
    background-image:url(../images/contentbg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:536px;
    background-position:top left;
    color:white;
}
```

try adding `overflow-x: hidden;` and possibly also `width: 100%;`

or try adding

```
html{
     width:100%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

play around with these, the right combination should make it work OK.

Comment: i love you!!!!!! you saved me alot of time. thats going into my notes :p thank you. ( i think the width:100% did it, why didnt i think of that lol. )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CSS has several things with large widths or margins which could be invisibly going off the side of the page - most likely a positioning difference between IE and other browsers.

In firefox, the firebug addon allows you to inspect all the elements of your page. If there's something like that for IE it should help you identify the offending element. Otherwise, maybe try setting all borders to a width of 1 pixel with various colours to try to highlight which element is sitting out there.

Comment: yea i have firebug but cant seem to detect anything. i did *{border: 1px solid green; } and i cant see anything that is off.

Comment: I just found this link if you don't already have it for IE. Hopefully it helps: http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Comment: I think the Web Developer Toolbar for IE7 from Microsoft works quite neat. I actually use it for testing over Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and this solved it for me:

```
html
{
    overflow: auto;
}
```